# I can't update in the terminal

Tags: command-line, updates

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I can't update in the terminal. Every time I try (by typing `sudo apt-get update`), I get the message:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists), which if you provided your full `apt-get update` output would show there were 404 errors and is ultimately the actual underlying problem.  (PPA doesn't offer packages for that version of Ubuntu, that is)

Answer (score 1):

The ppa you're trying to use does not support 18.04. If you used this command:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes`

to add it, use:

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:noobslab/themes`

to remove it.

Comment: I ran the above command and  here is what it gave me:

Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: You can remove it manually by navigating as root to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory and deleting the **noobslab themes** related one or two files. If there's one file only, it should have the *noobslab-something.list* extension. If there are two files, the other one should have the *noobslab-something.list.save* extension. After you delete both of them, run `sudo apt-get update` again.